# using fluidcontent (fluid powered TYPO3) in a TYPO3 multidomain setup

Tags: typo3, flux, fedext

I have an TYPO3 installation with two domains. Each domain has its own provider extension and static template file.

Example:
domain1.com -> providerextension1
domain2.com -> providerextension2

Is it possible to hide the fluidcontent FCEs from providerextension1 in domain2.com?

Example from Bootstrappackage (https://github.com/Ecodev/bootstrap_package)
As soon as an extension has included fluidcontent FCEs (like the fluidcontent_bootstrap) it will add these to all domains, also when the TypoScript Configuration is not included.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question completely, the answer is no: you cannot in TYPO3 make your TypoScript that is available in the backend, depend on the domain name being used. There is a way to make TypoScript conditions for the frontend output (for example a condition to only add template paths for your provider A when domain is X), but the same is not possible in the backend.

You are of course welcome to add a feature request on our issue tracker - I don't see any immediate problem with a feature to toggle on and off particular provider extensions based on for example a TypoScript setting. But you should keep in mind the limitation mentioned above since it implies that *in order to achieve your desired goal you must place each domain record on a page tree of its own and closely manage the TypoScript that controls the available Provider Extensions on each page tree*.

Put shortly: even if you get this feature request filled, it may not be the solution you want and you may have to restructure your pages and domains to get where you need to be.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the FCE are defined in the "ext_tables.php" and "ext_localconf.php" and these files are always loaded when the extension is enabled.

You can alter "ext_tables/ext_localconf" with a simple condition like

```php
if($_SERVER['server_name'] == "www.yourdomain.com") {
    //init FCEs here
}
```

Comment: I connect to the backend with foo.com/typo3. In the backend i have two domains: foo.com and bar.com. With this solution, it only will add foo.com FCEs, because of the logged in domain. This is no solution. Is there another way to filter the FCEs?

Comment: Use of environment variable conditions and in particular, hardcoded values such as domain names, is strongly discouraged in the extension configuration files. The pattern is dangerous and makes reproducing issues on different servers a very difficult, if not impossible task.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to override the template paths for one domain with an empty value or at least a path to an empty directory. Maybe `flux` is smart enough to ignore empty template paths.